# Can I possibly redirect <customErrors/> to another website and get the error message?

Tags: asp.net, custom-error-pages

I am trying to create a website that will redirect from website1 to website2 whenever there is an error and it will also get the error message using the `<customErrors />` on my *Web.config*. Unfortunately, I am getting a Runtime Error saying...
[image]

Here's my sample snippet.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="https://www.myanotherwebsite.com.ph" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Http404ErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

but when I change the *defaultRedirect=""* to another **WebForm.aspx** of my website1 it works perfectly.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="WebForm.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Http404ErrorPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: defaultRedirect="myanotherwebsite.com.ph" try this.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still getting the runtime error.

Comment: Make sure the redirect URL is working properly

Comment: yes, it is working properly